# cortex M3 bare metal execution

Tags: arm, cortex-m, keil, bare-metal

I am working on a STm32 project in Keil IDE. It contains a start-up file named startup_stm32f10x_xl.s has the following code in it

```
; Reset handler
Reset_Handler   PROC
            EXPORT  Reset_Handler             [WEAK]
            IMPORT  __main
            IMPORT  SystemInit
            LDR     R0, =SystemInit
            BLX     R0               
            LDR     R0, =__main
            BX      R0;-----------------;After execution this instruction
            ENDP
```

After the execution of the BX R0 instruction, the target system hangs and the execution does not enter the main function.

Kindly requesting every one to specify what may be causing this.
Thankyou

Comment: `__main` is a library function which clears the zero init section, copies initialised statically allocated variables from flash to ram, and runs constructors of statically allocated instances. Does your processor hardfault? You should be able to work out what's going wrong if it does.

Comment: processer does not hardfault

Comment: what does the disassembly show, specifically what is the address of __main and what value are they loading into r0 (should be __main | 1.

Comment: how do you know it is that instruction that is the problem and not something before it?  also where did this startup come from, was it part of a working example or created new for this project or something in between?

Comment: If you debug your software step by step at this point, where is your program going after that ? (I came across something similar when the MCU would go straight into an `InfiniteLoop` but it was with Atollic TrueStudio and was due to an issue in the linker script...)